# How to deal with dataset with missing items?

Tags: dataset

I collect some data with missing items.

```
data = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 11|>}];
```

It's not right to do `data[;; , #b &]`.

So how to set a default value for `b` as zero?

Or delete the row missing `b`?

Comment: Try `ds[All, "b"]`. It's alright to have a `Missing[]` entry.

Comment: This extract "b" only.I want the whole row.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
data[All, {"a", "b"}] /. _Missing -> 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which contains a value of 0 for b whenever it was missing before:

```
Normal @ %
(* Out: {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 11, "b" -> 0|>} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [`FailureAction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FailureAction.html) option of [`Query`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) to specify an action for a failure.

With `data` as defined in OP.

**`"Drop"` items that fail.**

```
data[;; , #b &, FailureAction -> "Drop" ] // Normal
```

> ```
> {2}
> ```

**`"Replace"` failed items with a placeholder**

```
data[;; , #b &, FailureAction -> "Replace" ] // Normal
```

> ```
> {2, Missing["Failed"]}
> ```

**Replace failed items with a default**

```
data[;; , #b &, FailureAction -> {"Replace", 0 &} ] // Normal
```

> ```
> {2, 0}
> ```

**Return failure objects**

```
data[;; , #b &, FailureAction -> "Encapsulate" ] // Normal
```

> ```
> {2, Failure[...]}
> ```

Hope this helps